# how to get search results and render them using datatables in a struts 2 application

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, datatables

I have a struts 2 application in which i want to use datatables to get results for a search and display them. the screen looks like below.

[image]

I want it to look like this finally and i want to use data tables to get the results from an ajax call.

[image]

I have an action class (Dashboard.java) with a method called viewSearchResult() as below.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.schenker.ocean.dao.SearchUpdateDAO;
import com.schenker.ocean.vo.Shipment;

public class Dashboard extends ActionSupport{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //members
    private String stt;
    private String hawb;
    private String chi;
    private String invoice;
    private String shipment;
    private String Search;
    private String tabIndex;
    private String searchType;
    private List<Shipment> aaData;
    public String getTabIndex() {
        return tabIndex;
    }
    public void setTabIndex(String tabIndex) {
        this.tabIndex = tabIndex;
    }
    public String getSearch() {
        return Search;
    }
    public void setSearch(String search) {
        Search = search;
    }
    //getters and setters for members
    public String getStt() {
        return stt;
    }
    public void setStt(String stt) {
        this.stt = stt;
    }
    public String getHawb() {
        return hawb;
    }
    public void setHawb(String hawb) {
        this.hawb = hawb;
    }
    public String getChi() {
        return chi;
    }
    public void setChi(String chi) {
        this.chi = chi;
    }
    public String getInvoice() {
        return invoice;
    }
    public void setInvoice(String invoice) {
        this.invoice = invoice;
    }
    public String getShipment() {
        return shipment;
    }
    public void setShipment(String shipment) {
        this.shipment = shipment;
    }

    //methods
    public String getDashboard(){

        return "success";
    }

    public String viewSearchResult(){
        SearchUpdateDAO sudao= new SearchUpdateDAO();
        aaData=sudao.getViewSearch(chi, stt, hawb, invoice, shipment, "");
        return "success";
    }
    public String assignSearchResult(){
        return "success";
    }
    public String shipDocsResult(){
        return "success";
    }
    public String assignUpdateResult(){
        return "success";
    }
    public String getSearchType() {
        return searchType;
    }
    public void setSearchType(String searchType) {
        this.searchType = searchType;
    }
    public List<Shipment> getAaData() {
        return aaData;
    }
    public void setAaData(List<Shipment> aaData) {
        this.aaData = aaData;
    }
}
```

And my jsp page (which also has the search menu on the left hand side) is below.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" HREF="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* $(document).ready(function() { */
    function postJSONData(){

        var view = $('#view').val(); 
        var assign = $('#assign').val(); 
        var search=$('').val(); 
        var stt=$('[name="stt"]').val();
        var hawb=$('[name="hawb"]').val();
        var chi=$('[name="chi"]').val();
        var invoice=$('[name="invoice"]').val();
        var shipment=$('[name="shipment"]').val();
            $('#viewTable').dataTable( {

            } );
        };       

    /* }); */

</script>
<title></title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  body {
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

  #header {
    /* background: #ccc; */
    padding: 0px;
    }

  #sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: #C7C7C7;
    }

  #content {
    margin-left: 22%;
    }

  #footer {
    clear: right;
    /* background: #eee; */
    padding: 0px;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border: none; padding: 0px;"> 
<div id="header">
    <table width="100%" height="20%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" height="1"
                style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;" id="ezlogowrap" colspan="5"><img
                src="images/ez-view-logo.png"></td>
            <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-right: 15px;"  colspan="5"><div
                    id="logowrap" align="right">
                    <img src="images/DbSchenkerLogo.gif" alt="DB Schenker logo">
                </div></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <tr><td  colspan="10" height="25%"></td></tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10"
                style="background: #000066; width: 100%; height: 36px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td  colspan="10" height="25%"></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<table width="20%" align="left">
                            <s:form name="searchForm" action="getDashboard" method="post">
                                <tr>
                                    <th align="center" colspan="2">Search</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                     <td colspan="1"><s:textfield size="20" maxlength="20" name="stt" key="label.stt"></s:textfield> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="1"><s:textfield size="20" maxlength="20" name="hawb" key="label.hawb"></s:textfield> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="1"><s:textfield size="20" maxlength="20" name="chi" key="label.chi"></s:textfield> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="1"><s:textfield size="20" maxlength="20" name="invoice" key="label.invoice"></s:textfield> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="1"><s:textfield size="20" maxlength="20" name="shipment" key="label.shipment"></s:textfield> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" style="padding-top: 2px;" colspan="2"><s:submit key="label.search"  onclick="postJSONData();" ></s:submit> </td>
                                </tr>
                                </s:form>
                            </table>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <table align="left">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="8">
    <div id="display jqueryDataTable">
        <table  id="viewTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>System</th>
                <th>Doctype</th>
                <th>STT</th>
                <th>HAWB</th>
                <th>CHI</th>
                <th>Invoice</th>
                <th>Shipment</th>
                <th>Shipdate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>System</th>
                <th>Doctype</th>
                <th>STT</th>
                <th>HAWB</th>
                <th>CHI</th>
                <th>Invoice</th>
                <th>Shipment</th>
                <th>Shipdate</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<table width="100%" height="20%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10"
                style="background: #000066; width: 100%; height: 25px;"><div
                    align="center" class="style1"
                    style="font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-left: 5px;">DB
                    Schenker, Inc. &copy; 2014</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <!-- <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" /> -->
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"/>
    <!-- <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="true" /> -->

    <package name="logindefault" extends="struts-default,json-default">

        <action name="login" method="execute" class="com.schenker.ocean.actions.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/searchpage.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

    <package name="default" extends="logindefault" namespace="/">

        <action name="login" method="execute" class="com.schenker.ocean.actions.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/searchpage.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="getDashboard" method="getDashboard" class="com.schenker.ocean.actions.Dashboard">
            <result name="success">/searchpage.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="viewSearchResult" method="viewSearchResult" class="com.schenker.ocean.actions.Dashboard">
            <result name="success">/searchpage.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>


</struts>
```

My question is how can i get datatables to call viewSearchResult() and pass the parameters in the searchform? And how can i make sure the response is handled by datatables and not forwarded to another page by struts?

Comment: Please see: struts2-json-plugin [http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html], you will want an action that renders the form and another that returns the relevant content as JSON.

Comment: @Quaternion DO you mean to say i have to have two action classes.. one takes the form input forwards it to the second action class which gets the results and returns them in Json format? Does this mean action chaining concept of struts2 has to be used? I have the search form and the results in the same JSP page. Does this pose any problems?

Comment: No - although that would be one way. But, you do need two actions so your options are: Create two action classes, use two different methods in the same action, or my favorite: add the conventions plugin and then you don't need to create actions for the views for forms just add a JSP in the right spot and it will render fine... you'll still need a class for the json action(s).

Comment: @Quaternion could you please show a struts.xml representation for "Create two action classes, use two different methods in the same action" I already tried the second method with two methods in the same action class  and declared the result type as json. But the result was forwarded to an empty page. I tried troubleshooting it for a day and realised im doing something fundamentally wrong. Im new to struts 2 by the way. Please excuse me if my doubts are really basic.

Comment: can we have a quick chat?

Comment: Sorry if you are new to struts2, every request is an action. So rendering the view is one, and getting the data with json is another. Please see: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/action-configuration.html (if the "method" attribute is added to the action tag you can state which method will be used. By default it is "execute()")

Comment: I am aware of how the method name and actions work. I did that yesterday and found that results were being returned in JSON format.. to an empty page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62769/discussion-between-quaternion-and-djr).

Comment: @DJR: I have the similar requirements. Can some one pls comment on the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591354/how-to-send-or-capture-datatable-1-10-parameters-in-struts2-action-class

Answer (score 0):

You can use struts-json plugin to get the response from action class in json format. Later to render use any one javascript approach (jQuery,jTable,dojo,etc.,)

To return as json object from a action class you have to set the return type as json in the struts action definition like below.

```
<action name="writeJSON" class="com.rajesh.json.ReadJSON" method="writeJSON">
<result type="json" />
```

To send and receive data to server and get response as json via ajax refer the below links.

[Send json data to struts 2 action](http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/)

[Read json data from struts 2 action](http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/read-json-object-from-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/)